# C++: Is it more efficient to store data or continually read it

Tags: c++, performance, storage

Ok so I'm working on a game project. Just finished rebuilding a game engine I designed some time ago. I'm looking at making a proprietary file type to store data rather than using a database like sqlite.

Looking at making this work with the game as efficiently and quickly as possible right off the bat without going too deep into it. And then improving over time.

My question is: Is it more efficient overall to load the data from the file and store it in a data manager class to be reused? Or is it more efficient overall to continually pull from the file?

Assuming the file follows some form of consistent structure for it's data. And we're looking at the largest "table" being something like 30 columns with roughly 1000 rows of data.

Comment: Depends, if you can hold it all in RAM and search thru effectively, probably better load it once and keep it there. If it's too much, you should use the disk. A hybrid solution throwing away data not used for a while could be the best to preserve some memory.

Comment: Caching in memory is always going to be faster, but... Do you have memory available to hold it? Is there any need to cache and hold? If you access rarely and there is enough other stuff going on fast or slow data manager may be utterly irrelevant. Start with the easiest one to write and see if there is any impact.

Comment: 30 cols x 1000 rows is tiny.

Comment: You can let the OS memory manager deal with this problem by using a memory mapped file.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to give you any type of definitive answer.   Benchmark your code and find out the answer in your specific case.

Comment: Always profile, never guess. If you are writing good maintainable code it should not be difficult to easily AB test both options to see which is better for your use case. Knowing that keeping data in memory is probably faster doesn't help at all if you don't have the memory to do it, so you'll likely need a mixture of both anyway.

Comment: "30 cols x 1000 rows is tiny" is untrue if each cell is large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a handy chart of "Latency Numbers Every Computer Programmer Should Know"

[image: Latency numbers every computer programmer should know]

The far right hand side of the chart (red) has the time it takes to read 1 MB from disk. The green column has the same value read from RAM.

What this shows us is that you should do *almost anything* to avoid having to directly interact with the disk. Keeping data in RAM is good. Keeping data on disk is bad. (Memory mapped files might provide a way to handle this.)

This aside, reinventing the wheel is almost always the wrong solution. Sqlite works and works well. If it's not ideally suited for your needs, there are other file types out there.

If you're "*looking at making this work with the game as efficiently and quickly as possible right off the bat without going too deep into it. And then improving over time*", you'll find that's easiest to do if you reuse preexisting solutions to common problems.

Comment: As said in my answer, it's not really fair to compare RAM access time to disk access time if you keep reading the same data, as, before hitting the disk, you are going to meet the C runtime cache, the operating system disk cache and the disk controller cache itself, so you are probably going to pay only a latency penalty (due to the context switches), not really a disk read time penalty.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Acknowledged, though it seems like a poor choice to rely on an opaque series of caches to save you from huge latency hits when you could design solutions which avoid the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping reading from a file is generally not a good idea; modern operating systems do keep large IO caches (so if you keep reading the same stuff it won't *really* hit the disk), but syscalls are of course way more onerous than straight accessing memory - although, whether this is actually going to be a performance problem for your specific case is impossible to judge with the information you provided. On the other hand, if you have a lot of data to access keeping it all in memory can be wasteful, slow to load and, when under memory pressure, lead to paging.

The easy way out of this conundrum is to map the file in memory; the data is automatically fetched from disk when required and, unless the system is under memory pressure, frequently accessed pages remain cached in RAM, guaranteeing you fast access.

Of course this is feasible only if the data you need to map is smaller than the address space, but given the example you provided (30 columns/1000 rows, which is really small) it shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score -1):

If you can hold the data in RAM then it is more efficient. This is because it is quicker for your computer to access values that are in RAM, a cache or the CPU's registers than it is to get it from the hard drive. Reading from the hard drive requires alot of time from the drivers of the operating system; therefore holding the data is more efficient

Comment: There is potentially a LOT more complexity than what you've addressed here.  The question itself is insufficiently detailed to allow any kind of specific answer.